# Regular Expression [^.] in Python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

```
import re
str="Everyone loves Stack Overflow"
print(re.findall("[ESO][^.]",str))
```

I don't understand why `[^.]` does anything. I thought it only matches characters that are not characters - in other words: nothing! But the output is the following:

```
['Ev', 'St', 'Ov']
```

Can someone shed some light on this? It's impossible to search for something like `[^.]` on google, and pythondocs about regular expressions didn't help either.

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Sentinel This is only so I could understand the concepts better. Will help in future endeavors ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most of the regular expression special characters lose their special meaning within a character class (square brackets), so while `.` matches any character, `[.]` matches a literal `.` and `[^.]` matches any character other than `.`.  You will sometimes see people wrap a character like `.` in square brackets just to make sure it's treated literally without having to worry about any corner cases in a regular expression library.

Comment: D'uh! I've been staring at it for half an hour and couldn't understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Character classes `[]` have their own little language. Specifically, the dot `.` inside a character class matches the actual `.` (and is not a wildcard).

Answer (score 3):

Most characters lose their special meaning when they are inside a character group.

So `.` matches any character, but `[.]` matches only dot. Thus `[^.]` matches everything that is not dot.